# Side Menu not showing correctly

Tags: ios, swift

I am using a third-party [Side Menu](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SideMenu).

I did exactly what the tutorial do, but I can't get the menu to show.
It just slide out a black page, which supposed to be the side menu.

And here's the warning :

> SideMenu Warning: menuLeftNavigationController cannot be modified
>   while it's presented. 2016-12-03 17:27:44.533
>   [95337:11887108] Warning: Attempt to present
>     on
>    which is already presenting

I've been trying to tackle this for hours, I also asked people who made the menu but...

Anyone could please point out what might goes wrong?

Comment: Here is some solution may help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25213152/warning-attempt-to-present-modaltableviewcontroller-on-maintableviewcontroller) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32696615/warning-attempt-to-present-on-which-is-already-presenting-null)

Comment: I know it's late, but this [link](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu/issues/194) solved my problem. Hope it userful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your initial UIViewController embed in Navigation Controller,

Comment: Perhaps provide some example code to elaborate on this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Goto SideMenuManager.swift file and comment the following code( i comment this code in pod and my menu is working properly)
guard oldValue?.presentingViewController == nil else {
print("SideMenu Warning: menuLeftNavigationController cannot be modified while it's presented.")
menuLeftNavigationController = oldValue
return
}

[Screenshort:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j63W6.png)