# Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController> on <RNNSideMenuController> which is already presenting <RCTModalHostViewController>

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, square

I am using [in-app-payments-react-native-plugin](https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-react-native-plugin) plugin to integrate Square payment method in react native. In iOS, it's creating an issue if opening a card entry model on Add new card react native popup. I am having a popup to add new credit card details, and getting this warning from the package when calling card entry model inside a popup. It's working on android and also with iOS if not calling from popup screen.

Warning inside Xcode::

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x7fba6b163400>  on <RNNSideMenuController: 0x7fba6b15fa00> which is already presenting <RCTModalHostViewController: 0x7fba6d798340>
```

I am using Xcode version "11.0" and react native "0.61.4".

This objective-c code of package generating this warning::

```
UIViewController *rootViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.rootViewController;

if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
    [((UINavigationController *)rootViewController) pushViewController:cardEntryForm animated:YES];
} else {
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:cardEntryForm];
    [rootViewController presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Here the if a part is working but if statement generating this warning. I am new to objective c. Please suggest what is a problem occurred here.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I have a feeling it's related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32696615/warning-attempt-to-present-on-which-is-already-presenting-null but I also don't have the iOS knowledge to implement this.

Answer (score 2):

Two modals cannot be open at the same time. On iOS, even opening modals consecutively may trigger this. For my case, i closed the first modal, and set a time out of 500ms before opening the second one. It solved my problem.

Comment: If working in React Native, just wrapping the second call to open a modal in `setTimeout` with a delay of `0`, which simply sets the call at the bottom of the stack, may be enough.