Error: Attempt to present MFMailComposeViewController which is already presenting
I try to add a native Splash Screen to my Flutter iOS App with this tutorial:
https://medium.com/@obenkucuk/flutter-native-splash-animation-with-lottie-on-ios-3c8660b41dde
I added to AppDelegate:
 // Runs the default Dart entrypoint with a default Flutter route.
    flutterEngine.run()
      
    // Used to connect plugins (only if you have plugins with iOS platform code).
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self.flutterEngine)

and my SplashViewController looks like:
import UIKit
import Lottie
import Flutter

public class SplashViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private var animationView: LottieAnimationView?
    
    public override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        animationView = .init(name: "splash")
        animationView!.frame = view.bounds
        animationView!.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        animationView!.loopMode = .playOnce
        animationView!.animationSpeed = 1.00
        view.addSubview(animationView!)
        animationView!.play{ (finished) in
            self.startFlutterApp()
        }
    }
    
    func startFlutterApp() {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let flutterEngine = appDelegate.flutterEngine
        let flutterViewController =
            FlutterViewController(engine: flutterEngine, nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        
        flutterViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        flutterViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        
        present(flutterViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
}

It is working but I have one Problem if I try to send a mail with the package flutter_email_sender. This error seems to be a problem with MFMailComposeViewController:
Attempt to present <MFMailComposeViewController: 0x1508ed800> on <Runner.SplashViewController: 0x147f131c0> (from <Runner.SplashViewController: 0x147f131c0>) which is already presenting <FlutterViewController: 0x14a25f800>.

This solution is not helping me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59336348/3037763
How could I modify my controller to work with MFMailComposeViewController as well?

This means you're not allowed to present another ViewController if one has already been presented. You can try this approach to replace the root window controller with your main FlutterViewController.
func startFlutterApp() {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let flutterEngine = appDelegate.flutterEngine
    let flutterViewController =
        FlutterViewController(engine: flutterEngine, nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = flutterViewController //<- here

    if let window = appDelegate.window {
        UIView.transition(with: window, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: nil)
    }
}


Wow, that is working! But now I have a short black screen between the splash and the Flutter View.

Hmm, I guess you need an animation transition here, I edited the answer. Maybe that's weird black screen is your default background or tintColor of the window.
